# How do I reliably change the indentation width in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I tried to change the width of indentation of my Eclipse IDE to 2 via `Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Displayed Tab Width`.

However, when I press <kbd>tab</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd>, I still indent or un-indent by 4 spaces.  Why?  This still occurs even after restarting Eclipse.

Comment: Possible same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650652/changing-editor-tab-width-in-eclipse-3-5

Comment: New answer with additional info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650652/changing-editor-tab-width-in-eclipse-3-5/58494110#58494110

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you search in preferences for the code formatter, I think you will find what you're looking for.  It should be located under: `Java > Code Style > Formatter`

There should be a tab labeled `Indentation` with the settings which you seek to tweak.

[image]

Also, see [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Default-Format-Settings-in-Eclipse) for how to set up the formatter to auto-format your code with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: I've set up the formatter to do 4 spaces as you've shown here and in the link at the bottom. When I run teh auto formatter, it still changes everything to use 2 spaces instead of 4.

Comment: Happy new year @StealthRabbi!  Are you trying to get 4 spaces or a single tab (with the size of 4 spaces like what is shown)?  If it's not taking, you can try renaming the profile and then re-applying the formatting.